# Site being loaded without SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, http, https

There is a certain site I frequent daily. I just noticed that when I enter it, it is loaded with **http** instead of **https**. I checked it's certificate using [this service](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and it says it is still valid for 4 months yet. So, what could be causing it to be loaded in the insecure manner? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will do so unless you explicitly ask for https.  Are you doing that?

Comment: AFAIK, when I don't specify it, it will load with https, right? For example, if I just type somedomain.com, it will redirect to the https right?

Comment: No.  Not unless the website itself redirects you.  Browsers will use http by default.